# How do i get the selected value in select dropdown of x-editable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I am using x-editable in angularjs.

When i submit the select.

I do not get the new value with $data as given in documentation

here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/7014/

script :

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable", "ngMockE2E"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $q, $http) {
  $scope.items = ['a','b','c'];
  $scope.user = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'a'
  };

  $scope.updateUser = function(data) {
      alert(data);
     $scope.console = data;
    return $http.post('/updateUser', {id: $scope.user.id, name: data});
  };
});

// mock `/updateUser` request
app.run(function($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.whenPOST(/\/updateUser/).respond(function(method, url, data) {
    data = angular.fromJson(data);
    if(data.name === 'error') {
      return [500, 'Error message']; 
    } else {
      return [200, {status: 'ok'}]; 
    }
  });
});
```

Can anyone help me out, how do i get the updated value?

Comment: What is $data supposed to be? You need to have something you set in the scope, like updateUser(user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your trying to read s.text in your html, but you don't have a text key in your array!

Change....

```
ng-options="s.text as s for s in items"
```

to

```
ng-options="s for s in items"
```

and it seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/v983ryrk/1/

Comment: Thanks for example in jsFiddle, it solves my issue to get select data from dropdown.